# How to count how many times a value repeats a minimum number of times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns. The first being `time` which is just counting up from 1.

The important one is a bunch of 1's and 0's. I want to know how many times 1 repeats a specific n times. For instance, let's say I have 100 values of randomly placed 1's and 0's, I want to know how many times I have at least five 1's in a row. Meaning that I'd like to know the number of times it repeats 5, 6, 7, or anything greater number of times.

Has anyone done anything similar to this before?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample dataset?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to this question.

Comment: This is a typical state machine problem and comes with the typical design questions. In the situation you have 6 consecutive ones, does the count reset at the fifth? does the count continue to find another group overlaped with the first group? Or, if there are 7 ones, do you find only one group or three groups?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], 100))

(df.groupby(df[0].ne(1).cumsum().where(df[0] == 1)).count() > 4).sum().values[0]
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to know besides how many, how long each repetition chain is and even where it is?
Consider the following function:

```
def consec_ones_cntr(it, thrshld):
    n = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(it):
        if v:
            n += 1
        else:
            if n >= thrshld:
                yield i-n, n
            n = 0
```

I feel free to use @ScottBostons sample data:

```
# import  numpy as np
# import pandas as pd

# np.random.seed(1234)
# df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], 100))
```

Then the usage of the function would be:

```
print(list(consec_ones_cntr(df[0], 5)))
```

which results in

```
# [(7, 5), (70, 7)]
```

meaning that there are 5 ones between index 7 and 11, and another 7 ones between 70 and 76.

Comment: First off, thank you for your answer. This is awesome & I'll definitely use it. But, I'm confused how to read the output. I understand the 5 & 7 tell me how many 1's I have, but what do the 11 & 76 tell me?

Comment: They are the last indices of the related chain of 1's for indicating their positions in the array. However, as _first_ indices of sequences are usually the indicator of choice for position, I understand that you might simply want to change that by letting the search function `yield i-n, n`... :)

Comment: Btw, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Less elegant way to do it.

```
df['diff'] = df['Column'].diff()
df = df.fillna(0)
repeats = 0
y = 0
for x in df.itertuples():
    if x.diff == 0:
        y+=1
    else:
        if y >= 5:
            repeats += 1
        y = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `itertools.groupby`, with `np.unique`

```
import itertools 

x,y=np.unique([tuple(y) for x , y in itertools.groupby(df[0])],return_counts =True)
x
Out[343]: 
array([(0,), (0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
       (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (1,), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)], dtype=object)
y
Out[344]: array([13,  6,  3,  1,  1, 14,  5,  3,  1,  1,  1], dtype=int64)
```

For better display

```
df= pd.DataFrame(x.tolist()).assign(Number=lambda x : x.count(1),Unique=y).dropna(1)
df
Out[350]: 
    0  Number  Unique
0   0       1      13
1   0       2       6
2   0       3       3
3   0       8       1
4   0       9       1
5   1       1      14
6   1       2       5
7   1       3       3
8   1       4       1
9   1       5       1
10  1       7       1
```